# Can I delay my salah?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

**Isha prayer prayed late?**

For example, rather than praying at 8 for isha, I pray it at 10?

I sometimes find that when it comes time for prayer, not just in this, I am not concentrating.

Comment: As long as Fajr hasn't entered, it's not "too late". It's actually better for men to pray Isha late, at least in Hanafi.

Comment: Isha needs to be prayed before the mid night. It is better to delay it a bit but not till midnight. For more explanation and reference from hadith, please refer https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10125/timing-of-isha-prayer

Comment: I assume that there should be answers for the given question. Please search the site prior to asking questions. And consider using meaningful and related tags.

Comment: This isn't really answerable without more information, since the answer varies with the location and time of the year and on the madhab you follow. The valid time for Isha extends to Fajr according to the majority opinion, see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51336/). However it is makruh to delay it beyond half of the night, and it is recommended according to some madhabs to delay it till the first third of the night, see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51467/).

Answer (score -1):

I don’t have the exact reference but I believe delaying salah without a valid reason might be haram. There is a time set for the prayers. I normally pray esha just before I go to sleep. As I said earlier I don’t have the reference and I am not a scholar

Answer (score -1):

> ...Indeed, performing prayers is a duty on the believers at the appointed times. **Quran 4:103**

Allah has set time constraint for prayers, there is a 'from' and 'to' time limit for each prayer. It is not haram to pray even at the last minute as long as it doesn't exceed the time limit set for that prayer.

It is better to pray as early as possible when the prayer time comes, but isn't haram to pray later, that's why there is a 'to' time limit, because if you shouldn't pray a prayer later then there shouldn't be time limit.

Comment: Please try to focus on answering the asked question. For 'Isha' it is known that the prophet often delayes praying it and therefore delaying it to the end of the first third of the night is regarded as sunnah by most scholars.