# tahajjud . answer me plz

Tags: tahajjud

salaam, I wanted to ask that I didn't pray isha cuz I came home late from work in that case can I still pray tahajjud? cuz I've heard  people say first u have to pray isha then tahajjud so can I still pray tahajjud after 12 after missing isha?

Comment: Isha is obligatory whereas tahajjud is supererogatory. You should worry about doing it first. If you got late you still have to pray it. And 12 is not necessarily late, as there are madhabs who say that the time for Isha lasts till dawn https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51336/